# AWS ASG replacement strategy

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, aws-cdk, aws-auto-scaling

I have successfully created an ASG with rolling update which seem to work. I have however, a rather unique use case. I would like to have a update strategy where I run both in parallell (EC2_old and EC2_new). Meaning, I want to make sure the new one is up and running during a test session of 15-30 min. During these 15-30 min I also want the deployment process to continue and not get stuck in a waiting mode for this transition to become complete. In a way I'm looking for a blue/green deployment strategy and I don't know if it is even possible.

I did some reading and came across `WillReplace` [update policy](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-attribute-updatepolicy.html#:%7E:text=Properties-,WillReplace,-Specifies%20whether%20an). This could do the trick but the cfn options seem rather limited. Has anyone implemented an update strategy of this complexity?

Current policy looks like this:

```
updatePolicy = {
    autoScalingRollingUpdate: {
        maxBatchSize: 1,
        minInstancesInService: 1,
        pauseTime: "PT1H",
        waitOnResourceSignals: true,
        suspendProcesses: [
            "HealthCheck",
            "ReplaceUnhealthy",
            "AZRebalance",
            "ScheduledActions",
            "AlarmNotification"
        ]
    }
};
```

Comment: You need CodeDeploy to manage your update.

Answer (score 0):

willReplace won't be a blue/green strategy. It does create a new ASG, but it will swap the target group to the new ASG instances as soon as they are all healthy. If you google aws blue green deployment you should find a quick start that goes over how to set up what you are looking for.